# Need to print only 13 to 16 characters(number/alphabet) in a file and store it as variable to use later to call using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file named output.txt with output as below.

```
cluster_id 2
disk_id 23
Master_cluster_change_id 567
```

I would like to extract only the numbers from each lines of the file and store as different variables to call later in the script. I am new to batch scripting and i am developing a query code based out of that. Tried using findstr but unable to extract only numbers and store them separately as 3 different variables. Please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the values in variables named like the first text on each line.

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (output.txt) Do Set "%%A=%%B"
set | find /i "_ID="
```

---

```
> SO_54258819.cmd
cluster_id=2
disk_id=23
Master_cluster_change_id=567
```

**EDIT variant with a prefix `_` for the variable name**

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\18\SO_54258819.cmd
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (output.txt) Do Set "_%%A=%%B"
set _
```

---

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\18\SO_54258819.cmd
_cluster_id=2
_cluster_name=xyz
_disk_id=23
_disk_name=123
_disk_peer=yes
_disk_type=type1
_Master_cluster_change_id=567
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, if an answer solves your question or you find it helpful consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Hi, I again need a help. my file has 

cluster_id 2
disk_id 23
Master_cluster_change_id 567
cluster_name xyz
disk_name 123
disk_type type1
disk_peer yes


and so on, say upto 50 or 100 lines one by one. can we assign one variable for each parameter so that it can 
be called again in the script,

@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (output.txt) Do Set "%%A=%%B"
set | find /i "_ID="

Can this be modified to assign variables to all type of values after that space like this.

cluster_id=2
disk_id=23
Master_cluster_change_id=567
cluster_name=xyz
disk_name=123

Comment: The above batch will set **all** pairs from the file into variable=value. If they are unique you can recall them all. To better distinguish from other environment variables you can prefix them with an underscore. See changed answer. BTW still no voteup or accepted answer.